# Secrule modsecurity random numbers and adress ip post method

Tags: apache, mod-security, mod-security2

I have an attack on my server, several thousand logs.
Please take a look. I am looking for a method that could help me block these queries to my wordpress. I tried to block by IP, but there are others as well. This post query - is still the same

> index.php=**huya$$()owy**3419**magor** <- Only the number changes.

Is it possible to block POST requests with random numbers in the middle of the text?

Can you give me a hint? I could not find such information.

My logs:

[image]

Look at the logs. Only the number in the middle changes.
I've got thousands of it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the fastest rule could be like this:

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI "@beginsWith /index.php=huya$$()owy" \
    "id:900101,\
    phase:1,\
    t:none,\
    block,\
    msg:'WPadmin \"owy\" attack.',\
    log"
```